# xamarin forms : how to disable past time in timepicker

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have a timepicker i am showing time on load adding one hour additional. What i want when user click on any past time it should disable the past time .... here is my code what i am trying but this code is not working

```
private void MyTimePicker_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.PropertyName == TimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName)
            {

                if (tmpickerfrom.Time < DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)))
                {
                    tmpickerfrom.Unfocus();
                tmpickerfrom.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

            }


            }


        }
```

Comment: If the user set the past time, you want to make the timepicker to disappear?

Comment: no, if user select past time timepicker should unfocus and set back to original time

Comment: If you set the TimePicker to the `Unfocus`, Users can not click it any more, is that your needs?

Comment: no, whe it unfocus timepicker shoul back to its origianl time

Comment: can't you set the time options to now and forward when loading the screen and binding data?

Comment: any example for this?

Comment: When I set the `tmpickerfrom.Unfocus();` Here is a running GIF https://imgur.com/a/Kqq77SX the TimeDialog cannot push up when you click it.